# WordPress PHP file permissiosn

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this is not the correct place to ask this but I don't where else to ask this, if you know of a place please let me know, thanks.

My website(wordpress) has just been hacked and files have been changed, I would like to know how they would have been able to access the files on the web server? Is this due to permissions or is does WordPress allow this?

Thanks in advance I really appreciate any answers.

Comment: It's ultimately your fault. Not Wordpress', not the server's. Yours.

Comment: the list of possible entry points is very large.

Comment: I'm afraid this is indeed not a good place for this question; as a first point of reference & help check out [WordPress Codex - FAQ My site was hacked](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Comment: @STT LCU, yes I know it is my fault I never said it was anything else's fault, and I was wondering if it were the permissions(which I set), and I know that this isn't the correct place to ask the question, but the other people who responded weren't so pathetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be many things, depends what theme/s, plugin/s you were using, also did you updated your wordpress.

Why You Should Never Search For Free WordPress Themes / Plugins

http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/

My wordpress site was hacked

http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Thanks Polo Pakina, appreciate you spending time to help me, I will try this out, thanks again!